# How to find words with more than one accent

Tags: regex, perl, nlp, text-processing

I have a list of thousands of lines and am trying to identify those lines that include words with more than one accented character for further analysis. There might be words separated by dashes, those are only interesting if one of their parts contains at least two accented characters.

From the following list

```
caouennec lanvézéac
caouennec lanvezéac
caouennec-lanvezéac
caouennec lanvezeac
caouennec-lanvézéac
```

I want to find

```
caouennec lanvézéac
caouennec-lanvézéac
```

Answer (score -3):

I was successfull finding those lines using the following (Perl flavoured) Regex:

```
^.*[ÁÉÍÓÚáéíóú][^- ]*[ÁÉÍÓÚáéíóú].*$
```

Matches every line that contains a group of characters that is not separated by a space or a dash but that contains more than one of the specified characters.

Comment: I am not sure why anybody should downvote this answer? It is correct, complete and works for the question above - have I done anything wrong here which I do not understand?

Comment: I downvoted it, because it only covers a very limited subset of accented characters.

Comment: That is right, but those are the ones I am working with and I was asking for and you can add others easily. If there is a more elegant solution than listing them I don't know. But nevertheless, thanks for explaining!